# Swiftui List Update issue

Tags: listview, swiftui, observable

//the Appended data is actually the data from the push notification ind it would Append the new notification in the List view
Problem is that after updating the data in the Array the view is not Updating even though the date is successfully added in the array .//

//here is my view and Methods//

```
struct ContentView: View {

    
    @ObservedObject var notification = OnlyNotification()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
                List{
                    ForEach(notification.data, id: \.id){ Message in
                    NotificationCell(Message:Message)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NotificationCell: View {
    let Message:MyNotification
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text(Message.name)){
            Image(Message.imageName)
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                            .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(Message.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(Message.ImageLink)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle(Message.name)
    }
}
struct MyNotification:Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
    var ImageLink:String
    var Message:String
    var imageName:String {return name}
    
}
class OnlyNotification: ObservableObject{
    @Published var data = [MyNotification]()
    init() {
        let notification1 = MyNotification(name: "Rafael Nadal", ImageLink: "New", Message: "Hi Budy")
        addnotification(Data: notification1)
    }
    public func addnotification(Data:MyNotification){
        self.data.insert(MyNotification(name: Data.name, ImageLink: Data.ImageLink, Message: Data.Message), at: 0)
    }
    public func getData() ->[MyNotification] {
        return data
    }
    
}
```

// Appending item from AppDelegate//
let obj = OnlyNotification()

```
 obj.addnotification(Data: MyNotification(name: "\(notification.request.content.userInfo["Name"]!)", ImageLink: "New", Message: "\(notification.request.content.userInfo["Message"]!)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are displaying the data from ContentView

```
@ObservedObject var notification = OnlyNotification()
```

but elsewhere in your code you are using another

```
let obj = OnlyNotification()
```

and adding to it.
They are different objects.

Comment: sorry i'm a newbie can you please let me know how to instantiate the object of the class globalay so that i can utilize it in app delegate

Comment: Hard to tell what you want to do without your "AppDelegate" code and how you call it, but try this:
in your "AppDelegate" view, declare obj like this: "@ObservedObject var obj: OnlyNotification"

Comment: i'm getting FCM Payload in AppDelegate and from there im mapping the payload to the Observable class which have the function to add the data to the published array which is then used to create notification views

Comment: @ObservedObject var obj = OnlyNotification() this is not helping i have used it still view is not updating as but data is successfully added in the array

Comment: that is not what I suggested you do. This is what I suggest: "@ObservedObject var obj: OnlyNotification"  not "@ObservedObject var obj = OnlyNotification()"

Comment: this produces the error in the AppDelegate as App delegate don't have initializer to initialize this

Comment: as a newbie, you should read this Apple documentation, it will help you a lot: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score -1):

Declare the object outside the class globaly

```
 var Myinstance:OnlyNotification?
```

then inside the initializer of the class
do this

```
 Myinstance = self
```

then access this global instance anywhere to access the functions and objecs of the class of same instance

Comment: Don't do that! terrible idea.